# Google Play app link links to the Play homepage instead of the app detail page

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat

I have a link on my website leading directly to a specific Google Play application:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=en.my.app" target="_blank">Go to the app</a>
```

The link is based on the [official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#UriSummary).

The link opens the Google Play app and goes to my app as planned. But on some devices, the user lands on the Google Play homepage instead of the detail app page. The "some devices" run Android 7 and have Google Play (v9.8+) installed.

What might be wrong? Is it some kind of a setting that prevents accessing the app "deep link"?

It's quite frustrating especially that it works for other devices, e.g. Nexus 5 with Android 6 on it. I don't see a pattern. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the app? To do this go to Settings --> Apps --> Google Play Store -->Open by default (may be different on yours I'm running 8.0). From there you should be able to clear defaults and change supported link settings.

Comment: I just checked it on a device that shows the app page correctly and on another one that shows Play's homepage - and the settings are the same. Weird.